# Positioning livechatinc dynamically

Tags: jquery

We are using www.livechatinc.com LiveChat on our website. They write the livechat code to our page, after our page is loaded. I would like to position the livechat div on our page dynamically, after the page has loaded. If I try to do this using jQuery document.ready, it doesn't work, as the livechat div isn't in the DOM at that time.
Is there some jQuery function I can write to keep checking the DOM for the div, and once that div is found I can position it and stop checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used LiveChat specifically, but you may be able to accomplish this with `setInterval`. This allows you to run a function every so many milliseconds. For example,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
      myInterval = setInterval(function(){

         //run something like this every 3 seconds
         var livechat = document.getElementById("livechat-div");

         if(livechat){ //check if the div exists

            //if it does, position div

            //clear the interval since we no longer need to look for the div
            clearInterval(myInterval);

         }
      }, 3000);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HNRDe/